# API to know the kind of protobuf Message being sent in

Tags: protobuf-net

What is the API to know the kind of protobuf Message is being sent?

For example I use the following to get the SendNameMessage object.

> SendNameMessage sendNameObj =
>   Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix< SendNameMessage>(stream,
>   PrefixStyle.Fixed32);

How does a listener know what kind of message is being sent?

The following is my SendNameMessage class:

```
[ProtoContract]
class SendNameMessage
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string sendName { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int sendId { get; set; }
}
```

How do I know if the message being sent is sendName or sendId?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

protobuf (under any implementation) is just the serialization API. When talking on the wire, the *default* is that both ends already *agree* what the data is. For sending different types of messages, a few options present themselves:

1. have a wrapper object that simply has child objects to represent different message types. With protobuf-net *specifically* you can also map this directly to inheritance (since protobuf-net maps inheritance to encapsulation)
2. use a message header - some kind of data before your message that identifies this. In particular, if using the `Base128` prefix-style, you can include a field number that is sent with the message (it defaults to `1`, but an overloaded method allows you to specify this). You would then deserialize this via `Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix` which includes a delegate parameter to perform type resolution from the field number.

---

After the edit... you mention `sendId` and `sendName`, but the **message** is `SendNameMessage`. It will *always* be everything (except defaults) in that message. It could be both. It could be neither. So in *that* scenario, you would just deserialize it and check `.sendName` and `.sendId`.

Another common option *here* is to add a *discriminator*, perhaps simply an enum:

```
enum MesageType {
    Error = 0,
    Name = 1,
    Id = 2
}
```

and include *that* on the message:

```
[ProtoMember(10)]
public MessageType MessageType {get;set;}
```

Now you have an *explicit* way of expressing **your** meaning of message-type.

Comment: Marc I made a mistake in my question. I made changes to my question.

Comment: I thought there was an easier way of doing this than checking each member as I have at least 10 proto members.

Comment: @sonu - but that it just how *you* are choosing to use it. As far as the system is concerned `SendNameMessage` is the message. The fact that you are only sending individual properties is up to you...